# django manage.py runserver Unhandled exception

Tags: django

after setup all that django requires, i encoutered a problem to runserver. would anybody figure out what's wrong with it? thanks.thanks.

> C:\mysite>python manage.py runserver Validating models...
>
> 0 errors found March 12, 2014 - 15:17:27 Django version 1.6.1, using
>   settings 'mysite.settings' Starting development server at
>   `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK. Unhandled
>   exception in thread started by .wrapper
>   at 0x0000000003B1C400> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 93,
>   in w rapper
>       fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.
>   py", line 127, in inner_run
>       ipv6=self.use_ipv6, threading=threading)   File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line
>   167 , in run
>       httpd = httpd_cls(server_address, WSGIRequestHandler, ipv6=ipv6)   File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py",
>   line 109 , in **init**
>       super(WSGIServer, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python33\lib\socketserver.py", line 430, in **init**
>       self.server_bind()   File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line
>   113 , in server_bind
>       super(WSGIServer, self).server_bind()   File "C:\Python33\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 50, in server_bind
>       HTTPServer.server_bind(self)   File "C:\Python33\lib\http\server.py", line 137, in server_bind
>       self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)   File "C:\Python33\lib\socket.py", line 386, in getfqdn
>       hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name) UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbb in position
>   0: invalid start byte

Comment: I'm not sure why this is happening, but see what happens if you explicitly give the server address (i.e. `runserver 127.0.0.1:8000` or `runserver localhost:8000`).