# Exception using Django framework

Tags: python, django, exception

I'm trying to use Django Framework on a [Windows 10 Duplet Tab mini](https://incomobile.com/modelos/dupletmini/) to make easier my work. I already installed `Python 3.5.1`, Django Framework and all requirements to run.

My issue is that the command `python manage.py runserver` throws this exception:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x0396D978>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ALEJANDRO FRANCO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ALEJANDRO FRANCO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\ALEJANDRO FRANCO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "C:\Users\ALEJANDRO FRANCO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\ALEJANDRO FRANCO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ALEJANDRO FRANCO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\ALEJANDRO FRANCO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 115, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "C:\Users\ALEJANDRO FRANCO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\apps.py", line 22, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "C:\Users\ALEJANDRO FRANCO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 26, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "C:\Users\ALEJANDRO FRANCO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 50, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "C:\Users\ALEJANDRO FRANCO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 662, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\ALEJANDRO FRANCO\OneDrive\GitHub\GEM_site\gem\admin.py", line 2, in <module>
    from models import GrupoEstudiantil, Evento, Asistencia, Usuario
ImportError: No module named 'models'
```

I already try it in other applications I have in the same Tablet and they work, only this Project throws an exception. I saw in [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22345123/django-manage-py-runserver-unhandled-exception) to try running it specifying the server address, but it didn't work neither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
File "C:\Users\ALEJANDRO FRANCO\OneDrive\GitHub\GEM_site\gem\admin.py", line 2, in <module>
  from models import GrupoEstudiantil, Evento, Asistencia, Usuario

ImportError: No module named 'models'
```

The error says that it is unable to find `models`. So you will have to edit the file `GitHub\GEM_site\gem\admin.py`. Change *line 2*:

```
from models import GrupoEstudiantil, Evento, Asistencia, Usuario
```

to

```
from gem.models import GrupoEstudiantil, Evento, Asistencia, Usuario
```

Read more: [Modules](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html)

Comment: Didn't work... it wasn't the same Exception though

Comment: What was the new exception?

Comment: This [one](http://pastebin.com/D4c8SC8Y)

Comment: In `gem/views.py` change `from models...` to `from gem.models...`. Similarly make the change everywhere in your app

Comment: That guide me to the real issue... all this time I missed to do `pip install Pillow`

Answer (score 1):

As the error already says, you are missing the [django-admin-bootstrapped](https://github.com/django-admin-bootstrapped/django-admin-bootstrapped) module. Install it first using:

```
pip install django-admin-bootstrapped
```

Comment: I edited my code, I pasted the wrong exception, sorry... but your answer gave me an idea of what my problem is: I'm missing module 'models', but when I try to install that module it also have an exception that ends up in `ImportError: No module named 'base'` but I can't install that last module.